# HTML to PDF - Bad performance

Tags: c#, html, performance, pdf, pdf-generation

I´m using [ExpertPDF](http://www.html-to-pdf.net/Support.aspx#csharp) (library for .NET C#) for converting **HTML to PDF** and my problem is that it takes a lot of time to do this.

Are there any customizations that will improve the conversion?

The HTML-page contains table-data with just a few images, so it is not that complex.

Have anyone else ever experienced this problem, or do you recommend another library for doing this?

I´m thankful for all hints I can get, there must be a way to increase the performance of this action...

Comment: Are you using standard html, xhtml, css? are your images large? i would imagine theses all would vary the conversion process.

Comment: The webpage-output is xhtml with css includes, there are no inline styles.

The images are not large and the format is *.jpg.

Do you have any special tips for optimizing the output even more?

Comment: Which version of ExpertPDF are you using?  We are using it (both v5 and now 6.2.0) and performance is very good.  We are rendering large tables which run to multiple pages with CSS without any performance issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really need build from HTML, i suggest to have a look [websupergoo](http://www.websupergoo.com), it is no free or open source library can export PDF from HTML.

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of questions in stackoverflow that speak for this subject

- [Generate PDF from ASP.NET from raw HTML/CSS content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/570179/generate-pdf-from-asp-net-from-raw-html-css-content)
- [Printing a PDF in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8749/printing-a-pdf-in-net)
- [How do I programmatically create a PDF in my .NET application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/177/how-do-i-programmatically-create-a-pdf-in-my-net-application)
- [see search result](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=html+to+pdf+.net)

Comment: I know there is a lot of questions about this subject, but, they dont solve my problem with the performance of ExpertPDF, html to pdf.