# Generating reports using custom data (html table) not dataset

Tags: c#, html, visual-studio-2008, html-table, export

I read several articles on this site and many others recommending report generating tools of various kinds but all use dataset as there datasource.

This is not my requirement!

I need some way to export the data which is displayed in the htmltable on mypage.aspx.

- user clicks view record
- a pdf opens (it should contain the data of the html table which is made dynamically)

I want to generate a pdf on the fly using a htmltable as a source of data and displaying it a a pdf doc in the browser *but not having to save the result to the webserver*.

Comment: No, and no need to write in uppercase as this is considered rude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may take a look at [iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/) and here's a [tutorial](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/80/Create-PDFs-in-ASP.NET-getting-started-with-iTextSharp) on how to get started. There's also a [section in the documentation](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/86/iTextSharp-Introducing-Tables) which illustrates how to create tables in PDF documents.

Comment: any way to use a general method, builtin method ?

Comment: Builtin what? The .NET framework does not contain any native way to work with PDF files.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this thread regarding [abcPDF](http://www.websupergoo.com/abcpdf-1.htm).  What you are describing is very similar to what I have used their library for.  When I was originally testing out various methods, I had tried [iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/) but found for the very minimal cost, [abcPDF](http://www.websupergoo.com/abcpdf-1.htm) did everything that I required (sepcifically HTML to PDF generation) with minimal lines of code.

[Generation PDF from HTML (component for .NET)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/598980/generation-pdf-from-html-component-for-net/712733#712733)