# How to render HTML chunk?

Tags: c#, .net, html

What's the best way to render a chunk of HTML in an application? We have a rich text editor control (from Karamasoft) in a web page, and need to generate a PDF with records saved from the control (with custom page headers, page footers, and record headers) so I need to be able to render the html so it can be "drawn" onto the page to be saved as a pdf.... is there any staright forward simple way to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/564650/convert-html-to-pdf-in-net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[HTML Renderer](http://htmlrenderer.codeplex.com) is a library of 100% managed code that draws beautifully formatted HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Without using any libraries, you can use the [Literal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.literal.aspx) control that allows you to inject the HTML you wish to display to the user.

Answer (score 0):

You may try PURE to render JSON data in HTML: http://beebole.com/pure/

Although this may be out of topic.

But then I'm interested on how do you convert the HTML in PDF.

What technical steps are involved?