# Save or output WebBrowser object context to .pdf file in VB.NET

Tags: .net, html, vb.net, winforms, pdf

I am loading an html page into a WebBrowser object in a VB.NET Windows Forms application.  The user may make changes to textboxes, dropdowns, etc. on the HTML page displayed in the browser.  I want the ability to save the current context to a .pdf file on the local HD.  I am able to print using WebBrowser.Print(), which shows the current context, but what ways are possible to get this saved as a PDF file locally?

Comment: There are third party libraries which can save html as pdf. Related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/564650/convert-html-to-pdf-in-net

Comment: I am looking to save the current context of the browser like I stated.  Any comboboxes or any other data on the form that is being changed.  Just the HTML to pdf is not what I am looking for.  I am looking for the current context of the WebBrowser object.

Comment: I have code that works fine but this post is so old you may not be interested any longer. If you are interested let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used CutePDF to accomplish this goal.

Answer (score 1):

I looked into this not too long ago for a project and basically, the only way to make this happen would be to use a third party component. I know that that isn't what you want to hear, but unfortunately, .NET doesn't have anything PDF related built in. :(