# Convert HTML to PDF in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert HTML to PDF in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564650/convert-html-to-pdf-in-net)

How can i use the acrobat driver to covert web page to pdf , i have a icon on my browser. How can i use that in ASP.NET to convert the web page to pdf pro grammatically.

Comment: Search first! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/564650/convert-html-to-pdf-in-net

Comment: @Josh Stodola: To be fair, this does ask specifically about the acrobat driver as opposed to ItextSharp.  You're right though, this has been addressed before.

Comment: i have acrobat installed on my system , i have a toolbar icon in the IE what im trying to know is can i use this function through program in ASP.NET application instead of opening each html doc in browser then clicking the icon. i dont know what is this -1 mean

Comment: Looks like clicking the icon will save you some money (that you'd pay for creating an app :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that you will need a server side library. [PDFSharp](http://www.pdfsharp.net/MainPage.ashx) is a good one that is free. They have a lot of [samples](http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/PDFsharpSamples.ashx).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the complexity of your web page, this free library may be your choice.
To parse html, you can use `HtmlWorker`. It has some weaknesses, though, e.g. how the styles are used. I'm working on a library based on iTextSharp but independent from HTMLWorker which would have better CSS support, but it's not finished yet.

[iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/)