# Convert HTML to PDF on ASP.NET (VB)?

Tags: asp.net, html, vb.net, pdf

I have data stored in the database with `HTML format`, and I want to get the value of this html content with MyReader.getString() after getting the html code I must do the `conversion` to `PDF` Format.

You have any idea on how can I do it ? !!

Comment: See [Convert HTML to PDF in .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/564650/convert-html-to-pdf-in-net).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Pdfcrowd](http://pdfcrowd.com) has an online API that lets you convert HTML to PDF. They have, among others, a client library for .NET. The API is pretty easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

Use a tool like webSuperGoo's ABCpdf, I've used it in the past and I found it quite easy to setup and use.

http://www.websupergoo.com/abcpdf-5.htm

Comment: I don't need a `software solution`, I need to do it manualy with for example a library like the `iText` in `JAVA`.

Comment: There isn't a built in library to do PDF conversion in .NET. I recommended ABCpdf because doesn't require an install of software on your web server - you just add the DLL to your project.

Answer (score -2):

You can put the whole HTML content into Word (as a HTML document) and extract it as PDF.

Comment: @Vincent: why?

Save the entire HTML to a document.
Add a Microsoft Word reference to your project and open your HTML document like this:

Dim objWord As Word.Application
Set objWord = New Word.Application
objWord.Documents.Open "<DRIVE>:\<path_to_your_file>.html", , , True

Now you can extract this document as a PDF document. (Explained here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/isvvba/thread/1bbecda8-d2fc-4578-983a-1de361367f19)

Comment: @AykutÇevik this isn't truly a solution but rather a hack or a work around. I like the idea because it doesn't include any third party libraries; but it's doesn't fit the OP's question or tags as the OP is talking about ASP.net which Word is not _technically_ a part of.