# convert html file into PDF file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, pdf, visual-studio-2008

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert HTML to PDF in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564650/convert-html-to-pdf-in-net)

I am using VSTS 2008 + C# + .Net 3.5 + ASP.Net + IIS 7.0 to develop web application. I want to convert html file/page/string into PDF file.

1. Any built-in solution from Microsoft to do this?
2. The top issue is about paging, i.e. how to map html conent to converted PDF page? e.g. I want to display an html table and an image in page 1 of converted PDF file, and display following html text after the image in original html into page 2 of converted PDF file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some online services to converting from HTML to PDF. Here are links

http://www.htm2pdf.co.uk/

http://www.pdfonfly.com/

http://www.adobe.com/products/acrobat/access_onlinetools.html

Also there are some services to do vise versa.

http://www.pdfdownload.org/free-pdf-to-html.aspx

http://www.convertpdftohtml.net/

Comment: I need some client libraries and tools, any ideas?

Comment: http://csharp-source.net/open-source/pdf-libraries

Answer (score 1):

Try ABCpdf.  Warning: it's not freeware/opensource.

http://www.websupergoo.com/abcpdf-8.htm

Sample from site demonstrating HTML support:

http://www.websupergoo.com/helppdf7net/source/4-examples/13-pagedhtml.htm