# how to write html content in pdf in .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf

i have a letter content in HTML in a string , i have to show it in a pdf format with all the styles and designs.

which possible method is there to convert it to pdf in C#,,

i have used  itextsharp,but when styles,images comes in the HTML it never comes in pdf.
pls help.. with some method to solve this problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert HTML to PDF in .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/564650/convert-html-to-pdf-in-net)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List of Open Source .NET PDF libraries here: http://csharp-source.net/open-source/pdf-libraries