# Convert webpage to PDF document using ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, html, pdf, itext

Is it possible to convert a webpage along with images and preserving styles into PDF document using open libraries like iTextSharp using C#.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/564650/convert-html-to-pdf-in-net

Answer (score 0):

Yes but.

iText[Sharp]'s style support is spotty at best.  Your absolute best html->pdf bet is [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/).  I haven't tried it personally, but it seems to have all its ducks in a row.