# Generating PDF reports from .NET

Tags: .net, html, sql-server-2008

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert HTML to PDF in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564650/convert-html-to-pdf-in-net)

I have a program in .net that gets the information from sql server 2008 and generates the reports to html page

I have to transfer that report to the pdf from so the user can view in pdf
but I don't want make use of reporting services

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: ask your question, it you don't want to get `use iTextSharp` answer

Comment: Do you want to generate reports directly to PDF, or to take your generated HTML and build PDFs out of them, or something else?

Comment: take my html and directly build pdf out of them

Comment: Take a look here: http://csharp-source.net/open-source/pdf-libraries

Comment: Asked and answered a hundred times.  http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[.net]+html+pdf