# Is there a way that I can convert a webpage into a pdf?

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf

I'm wondering if there is something out there where, if I press a button on an asp.net web page, I can programmatically create a pdf of that page and save it to my hard drive.

Comment: Have a look here (the questions are somewhat similar): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/564650/convert-html-to-pdf-in-net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this [HTML to PDF Converter](http://www.evopdf.com/?gclid=CMHh84X156gCFQUKfAod_RNcDQ)

[Generate PDF documents from a HTML page using ASP.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/HTML2PDF.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

[This is a pretty decent product for it](http://www.sautinsoft.com/products/convert-html-pdf-and-tiff-pdf-asp.net/html-to-pdf-jpeg-tiff-gif-to-pdf-asp.net.php), but I don't think it's free.

Here's an example of how it could be used.

```
var pdfVision = new SautinSoft.PdfVision();
var pdfBytes = pdfVision.ConvertHtmlFileToPDFStream("http://localhost/default.aspx");

//show PDF            
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "application/PDF";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition:", "attachment; filename=Result.pdf");
Response.BinaryWrite(pdfBytes);
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```