# Open Source library / tool for converting PDF to HTML?

Tags: c#, .net, pdf

My needs are quite simple, I need a tool or library (library would be perfect), to convert a PDF file to an HTML file keeping as many of the information as possible, except any images or styles, just semantic information.

I've checked out [iTextPdf](http://itextpdf.com/), but I haven't found anything like it. Any help would be nice.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This question has only been asked a couple dozen times already.  C'mon people.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert HTML to PDF in .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/564650/convert-html-to-pdf-in-net)

Comment: C'mon people. Please stop recommending HTML to PDF when asked about PDF to HTML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use iTextSharp. It's free and you only need the "itextsharp.dll".

http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/

Here is a simple function for reading the text out of a PDF.

```
Public Shared Function GetTextFromPDF(PdfFileName As String) As String
    Dim oReader As New iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(PdfFileName)

    Dim sOut = ""

    For i = 1 To oReader.NumberOfPages
        Dim its As New iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.SimpleTextExtractionStrategy

        sOut &= iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(oReader, i, its)
    Next

    Return sOut
End Function
```