# Convert (doc,docx,xls,xlsx,jpeg,jpg,txt,pdf,rtf) file into pdf by using asp.net code

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf-generation

I am searching any kind of tool which can be convert any kind of extension of them `(doc,docx,xls,xlsx,jpeg,jpg,txt,pdf,rtf)` into pdf file in asp.net code like `aspose` tool but its too much costly i want same functionality like `aspose` tool but `not much expensive`.

Please suggest me any kind of tool like this....

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

iTextSharp maybe would do the trick for you?
Here is a [link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/) for you

Answer (score 0):

3-Heights have a component (Document Converter) that does this. For HTMl there are several other alternatives (see here: [Convert HTML to PDF in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564650/convert-html-to-pdf-in-net)).

If you have full control over the web server, you could try to print those documents to a PDF printer or use an installed Acrobat Writer, though I wouldn't recommend this solution. It has somehow the smell of a hack...

**Edit:** [3 Heights Document Converter Service](http://www.pdf-tools.com/pdf/document-converter-service-office-pdf-pdfa.aspx)

Comment: this is only html to pdf convertor i am talking about any file convert into pdf not only HTML....

Comment: 3 Heights explicitly states office documents as well as some other formats. Adding a link to 3 heights.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure that if you want to put the time into it, the office com-interop objects can do it. Libre office has an api that can do it as well.