# write html page to the pdf file in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I can get my page's html code during my program and what I want to do is that I want to put this html page code in to the pdf file and My pdf file will be the same as my html page. is it possible ? if yes , how can I do this ?

Comment: Google asp.net html to pdf...http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=asp.net+html+to+pdf&sourceid=ie8&rls=com.microsoft:en-gb:IE-SearchBox&ie=&oe=&safe=on&redir_esc=&ei=qoN9T8_NOIKxhAej84G6DA

Comment: try this [Convert-Documents-to-PDFs](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17574/Programmatically-Convert-Documents-to-PDFs-the-Eas) and [convert-html-to-pdf-in-net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/564650/convert-html-to-pdf-in-net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [PDFSharp](http://pdfsharp.com/PDFsharp/) library to do that. I hope it will be helpful.