# Free tool to convert HTML to PDF file using .NET

Tags: c#, .net, html, pdf

I'd need to create a pdf version of my HTML pages using .NET 4.0. Is there any good free tool I can use?

I've seen some commercial tools but not any good free ones; ITextSharp doesn't seem to be performing well or able to handle table formats, etc.

Comment: Did you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804295/free-pdf-library ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert HTML to PDF in .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/564650/convert-html-to-pdf-in-net)

Answer (score 3):

We did extensive research (and testing) on this for a project in September 2011 and concluded that there were no tools that were both good (i.e. consistent, reliable rendering) and free.

Comment: kind of expected result I would say :-)

Answer (score 2):

http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/
It's a console utility that'll do it for you.

Comment: You can use Process class from System.Diagnostics to execute it.

Comment: @TheLight - you can use [Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to call an external program.

Comment: I'd need to install the tool separately on the server which is not easily possible... I'm looking for a .NET library so that I can add it to my application. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try [Amyuni WebkitPDF](http://www.webkitpdf.com). It is free for personal and commercial use and it provides bindings for C# and C++.

Here is a screen capture of this page using this library:
[image]

*Usual disclaimer applies*

Answer (score 0):

[Aspose.Words Cloud SDK for .NET](https://products.aspose.cloud/words/net) is a commercial product but its free trial plan provides 150 free monthly API calls. Maybe it suits your requirement. Its conversion is reliable and consistent.

```
// Get App Key and App SID from https://dashboard.aspose.cloud/
WordsApi wordsApi = new WordsApi(MyAppSid, MyAppKey);

var request = new ConvertDocumentRequest(
    document: File.OpenRead("C:/Temp/Test.html"),
    format: "pdf"
);

var result = wordsApi.ConvertDocument(request);
var fileStream = System.IO.File.Create("C:/Temp/Test.pdf");
result.CopyTo(fileStream);
fileStream.Close();
```

P.S: I'm developer evangelist at Aspose.