# Expert Pdf Software Components

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008

I am using Expert PDF Software Components for covering HTML to PDF using ExpertPdf.HtmlToPdf;
 But after conversion it shows watermark 
on PDF document
 "Expert PDF software components demo version"

Please help me how to remove this watermark

Answer (score 2):

It is because of the component you are using is evaluation version. I guess you'll need to purchase license to remove the watermark. If you have already purchased the license and still getting watermark, consider contacting customer support.

If you are here to seek some cracking solution, nobody is gonna help you here to crack it.

Comment: @user2126198: Then you should contact customer support of the component you are using. They will be able to help you more precisely...

Comment: @user2126198 : visit [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/564650/convert-html-to-pdf-in-net) or [here](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Export-GridView-To-WordExcelPDFCSV-in-ASP.Net.aspx). It may will help you. Otherwise try googling "Convert HTML to PDF in C#", it'll give you lots of suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

iTextSharp is good as it's the only PDF converter which is opensource and adds no watermark to the document. Moreover, it has some reasonable API reference documentation with it. Another option is, EVO PDF which is a good one as well, give both of them a try.