# Generate PDF from HTML with SAME Styles

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext

Here is my code in C# & its give instruction to load pdf.

```
public void SetPdfFormat()
{
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
     Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Panel.pdf");
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "filename=Panel.pdf");
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    pnlQuotation.RenderControl(hw);
    StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
    Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 100f, 0f);
    HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);

    pdfDoc.Open();
    htmlparser.Parse(sr);
    pdfDoc.Close();
    Response.Write(pdfDoc);
    Response.End();
}
```

But when I call that function pdf load as per html more items, but datatables are loaded with cells with borders. I need only borders for left/right margins, not for top and bottom.

Can I override and add css seperately for pdf cells?

Please give me solution with example codes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a .NET library here: http://www.winnovative-software.com/

I found this link by going to: [Convert HTML to PDF in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564650/convert-html-to-pdf-in-net)

I have not personally used this library.

Here is sample code of the winnovative software:

```
/// <summary>
/// Convert the HTML code from the specified URL to a PDF document
    and send the document to the browser
/// </summary>
private void ConvertURLToPDF()
{
    string urlToConvert = textBoxWebPageURL.Text.Trim();

    // Create the PDF converter. Optionally the HTML viewer width can
        be specified as parameter
    // The default HTML viewer width is 1024 pixels.
    PdfConverter pdfConverter = new PdfConverter();

    // set the license key - required
    pdfConverter.LicenseKey = "R8nYyNnI2MjRxtjI29nG2drG0dHR0Q==";

    // set the converter options - optional
    pdfConverter.PdfDocumentOptions.PdfPageSize = PdfPageSize.A4;
    pdfConverter.PdfDocumentOptions.PdfCompressionLevel = PdfCompressionLevel.Normal;
    pdfConverter.PdfDocumentOptions.PdfPageOrientation = PdfPageOrientation.Portrait;


    // set if header and footer are shown in the PDF - optional - default
        is false 
    pdfConverter.PdfDocumentOptions.ShowHeader = cbAddHeader.Checked;
    pdfConverter.PdfDocumentOptions.ShowFooter = cbAddFooter.Checked;
    // set if the HTML content is resized if necessary to fit the PDF
        page width - default is true
    pdfConverter.PdfDocumentOptions.FitWidth = cbFitWidth.Checked;

    // set the embedded fonts option - optional - default is false
    pdfConverter.PdfDocumentOptions.EmbedFonts = cbEmbedFonts.Checked;
    // set the live HTTP links option - optional - default is true
    pdfConverter.PdfDocumentOptions.LiveUrlsEnabled = cbLiveLinks.Checked;

    // set if the JavaScript is enabled during conversion to a PDF - default
        is true
    pdfConverter.JavaScriptEnabled = cbClientScripts.Checked;

    // set if the images in PDF are compressed with JPEG to reduce the
        PDF document size - default is true
    pdfConverter.PdfDocumentOptions.JpegCompressionEnabled = cbJpegCompression.Checked;

    // enable auto-generated bookmarks for a specified list of HTML selectors
        (e.g. H1 and H2)
    if (cbBookmarks.Checked)
    {
        pdfConverter.PdfBookmarkOptions.HtmlElementSelectors = new string[] { "H1", "H2" };
    }

    // add HTML header
    if (cbAddHeader.Checked)
        AddHeader(pdfConverter);
    // add HTML footer
    if (cbAddFooter.Checked)
        AddFooter(pdfConverter);

    // Performs the conversion and get the pdf document bytes that can

    // be saved to a file or sent as a browser response
    byte[] pdfBytes = pdfConverter.GetPdfBytesFromUrl(urlToConvert);

    // send the PDF document as a response to the browser for download
    System.Web.HttpResponse response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;
    response.Clear();
    response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
    if (radioAttachment.Checked)
        response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", 
                String.Format("attachment; filename=GettingStarted.pdf; size={0}", 
                pdfBytes.Length.ToString()));
    else
        response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", 
                String.Format("inline; filename=GettingStarted.pdf; size={0}", 
                pdfBytes.Length.ToString()));
    response.BinaryWrite(pdfBytes);
    // Note: it is important to end the response, otherwise the ASP.NET
    // web page will render its content to PDF document stream
    response.End();
}
```