# how convert html string to pdf using c#

Tags: c#, wkhtmltopdf

i have a string variable with html code and need convert to pdf the code of the variable, the variable is filled with the data of one gridview

```
<div>
<table>
<tr>
<td>Name</td>
<td>Cuty</td>
<td>Other Row</td>
<tr>
<td>Jonh</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<tr>
<tr>
<td>Name</td>
<td style="background-color:#00AA55;">Mary</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<tr>
</table>
</div>
```

and i need convert this table in  pdf including the row style. currently use  itext library but don't add the style on the document

Comment: See this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/564650/convert-html-to-pdf-in-net

Answer (score 0):

If you want a lot of painstaking work - create your own html -> pdf converter using PDFSharp (http://pdfsharp.com/). However, depending on the usage, I've heard using the internet explorer COM is a good solution. You can always print an HTML page to a virtual PDF printer.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but doesn't works for my, i will print the document without style.

Answer (score 0):

Use [PDFizer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfizer/), whenever you have valid xHTML (which you should always have).

It's pretty much the most reliable library out there.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but doesn't works for my, i will print the document without style.