# How would I convert HTML into a PDF document

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I need to create a registration form and when a user registers I would need to take that data and convert it to a PDF document and email that document, how would I go about doing this?

I am using Visual Studio 2012, .NET 4.5, ASP .NET, C# and HTML

Comment: Well, what have you tried?

Comment: Try searching for your question first. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/564650/convert-html-to-pdf-in-net, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/564650/convert-html-to-pdf-in-net/2129296#2129296, etc...

Answer (score 3):

You need to look at a library like [PDFSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfsharp/) or [PDFCreator](http://www.pdfforge.org/)