# Convert html data to pdf in devexpress using c#.net

Tags: c#

I need to display this  data to pdf please help me how to convert this html data to pdf

```
RichEditDocumentServer srv = new RichEditDocumentServer();
srv.LoadDocument("<html>fdhsdfd dshdsfgds</html>");       

using(Stream str= File.Create(@"D:test.pdf"))
{
     srv .ExportToPdf(str);
} 
Process.Start(@"D:test.pdf");
```

Comment: What problem are you facing? This didn't work? Do you show any errors?

Comment: actually this data needs to convert into pdf. i used above code but it  is showing error please help me

Comment: Illegal characters in path this is my error

Comment: In wich line? File.Create or Process.Start? Anyway, could yo put a `\ ` en the path? `D:\test.pdf`

Comment: i no need to put the path. if i put the path it will be work. i need that data convert the pdf plz help me

Comment: There are a lot of ways to convert HTML to PDF, I see that you choose RichEditDocumentServer from DevExpress so I guess that the solutions has to be attached to that! Your code looks good, you need to generate something, even an empty pdf, but ExportToPdf needs a Stream so why do you don't need to put the path? It seems like a basic requierement for .EportToPdf. Anyway, if you are simply trying method and you aren't attached to use a RichEditDocumentServer, check this link, maybe help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/564650/convert-html-to-pdf-in-net?rq=1

Comment: my requirement is like that. no needs to convert entire file. when  user enter some data that time it should be convert into pdf using dev express

Answer (score 1):

There are several commercial packages like AbcPdf and maybe Aspose and others.

If you are looking for a free solution, the best option might be [WkHtmlToPdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/), which is an EXE you call and send the URL or HTML to turn into PDF.

You don't have to write the `Process.Start()` code yourself though. It's kinda popular tool so there are several examples of how to use it including from C#, like: https://gist.github.com/johnnyreilly/2341776

There's also iTextSharp, but I think its CSS support is not that good.