# Show Page Number on PDF footer using pinpdf dll

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, pdf

I am using PinPDF dll to generate PDF file using vb.net .
I am able to see the objPDF.Footer method that accepts a static text to show at the footer. How to print "Page 1" "Page 2" at the and of each page footer using PinPDF dll

```
Dim objPDF As New Pintexx.Components.Web.pinPDF;
objPDF.Footer = "Monthly – Energy Conservation Indicators Report";
```

Answer (score 0):

pinpdf was retired in 2010 - so there is no longer any support for it - If no one knows the answer you may find it easier to use another pdf convertor.  There are some alternatives discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564650/convert-html-to-pdf-in-net)

Comment: I am trying to use ITextSharp using RenderControl(HTML to PDF)    How to print page numbers using ITextSharp.                                                                                                                                                                                                                        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
 
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

    pnlPerson.RenderControl(hw);

    StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());