# Rendering PDF from HTML with WebService

Tags: c#, web-services, pdf-generation, itext

I built a web application using ITextSharp to convert HTML into a PDF that is saved by the user. This works fine. Now though I am being tasked with creating a process to save the PDF to a share on a schedule. Since the entire PDF creation however is based on HTML I'm struggling on a way to do this with the removal of the front end.

Its hard to show code for this, so I hope I am getting the concept across well enough.

I tried creating a web service that I could trigger that would render the HTML and create the PDF and drop it, however I can't seem to find a way to make a webservice actually render a page. I'm not sure if thats even possible.

I basically want to see if anyone has any ideas before I go through the painful route of redoing the PDF design generation without using HTML.

Comment: You should check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/564650/convert-html-to-pdf-in-net

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways you can don this, here are a couple of suggestions of would I approach this problem:

-Recycle the code to a console app and run the code using a scheduled task.
-Run a scheduled task that will execute a web service within your web app.

Comment: Normally I'd say it would be nicer if you posted some code but since the OP didn't either I think it is okay! I completely agree with this! The way I've done this in the past is to make a single page on my site (page, not web service, no need for unnecessary complications), then download `wget` or `curl`, wrote a very simple batch file to hit that page and finally wrap that up in a scheduled task. These days you could probably PowerShell it, too, and skip `wget`.

Answer (score 0):

Just to elaborate on what MAlvarez and Chris Haas said, this might work for you:

1. On the server use curl or wget to obtain your HTML:

   wget -O - http://localhost:80/my/page.html > result.html
2. Post the result to your web service to render into PDF:

   curl -F file=@result.html -F outputName=result.pdf -F > result.pdf
3. Store the result.pdf where you need it (unless your web service can do it in step #2)

   curl -F file=@result.pdf -F storeTo=my/storage/resultpdf

The commands above are only indicative because only you know the parameters of your web service etc.

Answer (score 0):

So, still hard to post code but I was able to use HTMLGenericControls and Literals to build the entire page in the web service code and then use itextsharp to render that to a PDF.

Things like the table that the user facing version used a grid view I built into a Literal. The entire Page that I built in code then was handled by itextsharp and the PDF was generated into a filestream