# HTML To PDF conversion of invoice

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

**I want to convert this HTML invoice to PDF in .NET. I tried many libraries but none of them worked. When i tried to convert this HTML file to PDF it don't open up in adobe reader or any other software only in windows 10**

```css
h2, h1, td, th, tr
{
 font-family: Calibri Light;
 font-size: 11pt;
}

h2 {
 color: #084B8A;
 font-weight: bold;
 margin: 0em;
 font-size: 12pt;
}

h3 {
 font-family: Calibri Light;
 color: #084B8A;
 margin: 0em;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 16pt;

}

hr {
 border-width: 2px;
}

.small {
 font-size: smaller;
}

table {
 border: 0pt;
 margin: 0em;
 width: 100%;
 border-collapse: collapse;
}

tr.totals th {
 width: 12.5%;
}
tr.totals td {
 vertical-align: bottom;
}

th {
 text-align: left;
}
td {
 vertical-align: top;
 padding: 2px;
}
.center {
 text-align: center;
}
.right {
 text-align: right;
}
.bottom {
 vertical-align: bottom;
}

td.UBLLine
{
 color: #000000;
 margin: 0em;
 font-size: 8pt;
}

hr
{
color:#006666;

}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="PEPPOL.css">
<title>EHF Faktura og kreditnota</title>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
<td colspan="4">
<h3><b>Issue date</b> 
       2016-01-15</h3><br></td>
<td colspan="4">
<h3>Invoice Number
         

       28427</h3><br></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">
</td>
<td colspan="2">
</td>
<td colspan="2">
<h2>Buyer's order number </h2>57347539</td>
<td colspan="2"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="8">
<hr>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">
<h2>Supplier</h2>
<div class="UBLBuyerCustomerParty">
<div class="UBLPayeeParty">Roomservice AS<div>
</div>
<div>
</div>
<div><span class="UBLCityName">0275
         OSLO</span></div>
<div>
<div>TR</div>
</div>
<div><small>ID:  (ZZZ)
      4181</small></div>
<div><small>Company LegalID:  897742772</small></div>
<div><small>Legal name:  Roomservice AS</small></div>
<div class="small">
<div>VAT no.:  897742772</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</td>
<td colspan="2">
<h2>Supplier's contact information</h2>
<div class="UBLContact">
<div class="UBLID"><small>ID:  NV</small></div>
<div><span class="UBLTelephone">Phone:  22 21 90 50</span></div>
<div>
</div>
<div><span class="UBLElectronicMail">E-mail:  firmapost@roomservice.no</span></div>
</div>
</td>
<td colspan="2">
<h2>Customer</h2>
<div class="UBLBuyerCustomerParty">
<div class="UBLPayeeParty">ADVOKATFIRMAET HAAVIND AS<div>
</div>
<div>
</div>
<div><span class="UBLCityName">0101
         OSLO</span></div>
<div>
<div>TR</div>
</div>
<div><small>ID:  (ZZZ)
      11874</small></div>
<div><small>Company LegalID:  986420177</small></div>
<div><small>Legal name:  ADVOKATFIRMAET HAAVIND AS</small></div>
<div class="small">
<div>VAT no.:  986420177</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</td>
<td colspan="2">
<h2>Customer's contact information</h2>
<div class="UBLContact">
<div class="UBLID"><small>ID:  ARVE BJØRNVIK</small></div>
<div>
</div>
<div>
</div>
<div><span class="UBLElectronicMail">E-mail:  haavindfaktura@invoicedrop.com</span></div>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="8">
<hr>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">
</td>
<td colspan="2">
</td>
<td colspan="2">
<h2>Delivery date</h2>2016-01-18</td>
<td colspan="2">
<h2>Delivery location</h2><small>ID:  4573495349</small><div>
</div>
<div>
</div>
<div><span class="UBLCityName">0101
         OSLO</span></div>
<div>
<div>NO</div>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="8">
<hr>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">
<h2>Tax information (VAT on document)</h2>
</td>
<td colspan="2">
</td>
<td colspan="4">
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="TAXInformationHeader">
<td colspan="2"><b>Tax category and rate</b></td>
<td colspan="2">
</td>
<td colspan="2"><b>Taxable amount</b></td>
<td class="right">
</td>
<td class="right"><b>Tax amount</b></td>
</tr>
<tr class="TAXInformation">
<td colspan="2">H  <small>(= Reduced rate, food and beverage ),</small>  15.0% </td>
<td colspan="2">
</td>
<td colspan="2">8893.97  NOK</td>
<td class="right">
</td>
<td class="right">1334.03 NOK</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="8">
<hr>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="7">
<h2>Document totals</h2>
</td>
<td class="right small">
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="totals">
<th>Document lines' total amount</th>
<th>
</th>
<th>
</th>
<th>Amount excl.VAT</th>
<th>Total VATamount</th>
<th>Amount incl.VAT</th>
<th>
</th>
<th class="right">Payable amount</th>
</tr>
<tr class="totals">
<td>8893.97 NOK</td>
<td>
</td>
<td>
</td>
<td>8893.97 NOK</td>
<td>1334.03 NOK</td>
<td>10228.0 NOK</td>
<td>
</td>
<td class="right"><strong>10228.0 NOK</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="8">
<hr>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="8">
<h2>Payment means</h2>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>Means code</th>
<th>
</th>
<th colspan="2">Account no.</th>
<th colspan="2">Financial institution/operator</th>
<th>Payment reference/OCR</th>
<th class="right">Due date</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>31</td>
<td>
</td>
<td colspan="2">16451317060  <small>(BBAN)</small></td>
<td colspan="2">
</td>
<td>4003954817</td>
<td class="right">2016-02-01</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table>
<tr>
<td colspan="9">
<hr>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="UBLInvoiceLineHeader">
<td>
<h2>Line</h2>
</td>
<td>
<h2>Item number</h2>
</td>
<td>
<h2>Name</h2>
</td>
<td class="right">
<h2>Quantity</h2>
</td>
<td class="center">
<h2>Unit</h2>
</td>
<td>
<h2>Net unit price</h2>
</td>
<td>
<h2>Tax details</h2>
</td>
<td>
<h2>Allowance/Charge(line)</h2>
</td>
<td class="right">
<h2>Line amount</h2>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>5024</td>
<td>Kylling tempura, 8 biter</td>
<td class="right">1.0</td>
<td class="center">ZZ  


     </td>
<td>86.08696 NOK</td>
<td>H,  15.0% </td>
<td>Allowance:  0.00 NOK<small><div>Promotion discount</div></small>Charge:  0.00 NOK<small><div>Promotion discount</div></small></td>
<td class="right">86.09  NOK</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"> </td>
<td class="small">
<div><b>Orderline reference: </b>1</div>
</td>
<td colspan="6"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2</td>
<td>5025</td>
<td>Tempura maki, 8 biter</td>
<td class="right">1.0</td>
<td class="center">ZZ  


     </td>
<td>86.08696 NOK</td>
<td>H,  15.0% </td>
<td>
</td>
<td class="right">86.09  NOK</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"> </td>
<td class="small">
<div><b>Orderline reference: </b>1</div>
</td>
<td colspan="6"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>3</td>
<td>K1-K</td>
<td>Kjøretillegg kveld/helg sone 1</td>
<td class="right">1.0</td>
<td class="center">ZZ  


     </td>
<td>129.56522 NOK</td>
<td>S,  15.0% </td>
<td>
</td>
<td class="right">129.57  NOK</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"> </td>
<td class="small">
<div><b>Orderline reference: </b>1</div>
</td>
<td colspan="6"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>4</td>
<td>50204</td>
<td>Ekstra ris</td>
<td class="right">2.0</td>
<td class="center">ZZ  


     </td>
<td>17.3913 NOK</td>
<td>S,  15.0% </td>
<td>
</td>
<td class="right">34.78  NOK</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"> </td>
<td class="small">
<div><b>Additional information </b>- en reke chips</div>
<div><b>Orderline reference: </b>2</div>
</td>
<td colspan="6"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>5</td>
<td>4723</td>
<td>Luksus meny, 43 biter</td>
<td class="right">1.0</td>
<td class="center">ZZ  


     </td>
<td>539.13043 NOK</td>
<td>S,  15.0% </td>
<td>
</td>
<td class="right">539.13  NOK</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"> </td>
<td class="small">
<div><b>Additional information </b>- en reke chips</div>
<div><b>Orderline reference: </b>3</div>
</td>
<td colspan="6"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>6</td>
<td>K1</td>
<td>Kjøretillegg sone 1</td>
<td class="right">1.0</td>
<td class="center">ZZ  


     </td>
<td>86.08696 NOK</td>
<td>S,  15.0% </td>
<td>
</td>
<td class="right">86.09  NOK</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"> </td>
<td class="small">
<div><b>Additional information </b>- 3 pers</div>
<div><b>Orderline reference: </b>3</div>
</td>
<td colspan="6"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>7</td>
<td>4740</td>
<td>Medium mix, 16 biter</td>
<td class="right">1.0</td>
<td class="center">ZZ  


     </td>
<td>225.21739 NOK</td>
<td>S,  15.0% </td>
<td>
</td>
<td class="right">225.22  NOK</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"> </td>
<td class="small">
<div><b>Additional information </b>- 3 pers</div>
<div><b>Orderline reference: </b>4</div>
</td>
<td colspan="6"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>8</td>
<td>K1</td>
<td>Kjøretillegg sone 1</td>
<td class="right">1.0</td>
<td class="center">ZZ  


     </td>
<td>86.08696 NOK</td>
<td>S,  15.0% </td>
<td>
</td>
<td class="right">86.09  NOK</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"> </td>
<td class="small">
<div><b>Orderline reference: </b>4</div>
</td>
<td colspan="6"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>9</td>
<td>5082</td>
<td>Meny 3, 16 biter</td>
<td class="right">1.0</td>
<td class="center">ZZ  


     </td>
<td>181.73913 NOK</td>
<td>S,  15.0% </td>
<td>
</td>
<td class="right">181.74  NOK</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"> </td>
<td class="small">
<div><b>Orderline reference: </b>5</div>
</td>
<td colspan="6"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>10</td>
<td>5016</td>
<td>Scampi maki, 8 biter</td>
<td class="right">1.0</td>
<td class="center">ZZ  


     </td>
<td>77.3913 NOK</td>
<td>S,  15.0% </td>
<td>
</td>
<td class="right">77.39  NOK</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"> </td>
<td class="small">
<div><b>Orderline reference: </b>5</div>
</td>
<td colspan="6"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>11</td>
<td>5008</td>
<td>Ferske vårruller</td>
<td class="right">1.0</td>
<td class="center">ZZ  


     </td>
<td>86.08696 NOK</td>
<td>S,  15.0% </td>
<td>
</td>
<td class="right">86.09  NOK</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"> </td>
<td class="small">
<div><b>Orderline reference: </b>5</div>
</td>
<td colspan="6"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>12</td>
<td>K1</td>
<td>Kjøretillegg sone 1</td>
<td class="right">1.0</td>
<td class="center">ZZ  


     </td>
<td>86.08696 NOK</td>
<td>S,  15.0% </td>
<td>
</td>
<td class="right">86.09  NOK</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"> </td>
<td class="small">
<div><b>Orderline reference: </b>5</div>
</td>
<td colspan="6"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>13</td>
<td>5016</td>
<td>Scampi maki, 8 biter</td>
<td class="right">3.0</td>
<td class="center">ZZ  


     </td>
<td>77.3913 NOK</td>
<td>S,  15.0% </td>
<td>
</td>
<td class="right">232.17  NOK</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"> </td>
<td class="small">
<div><b>Orderline reference: </b>6</div>
</td>
<td colspan="6"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>14</td>
<td>5008</td>
<td>Ferske vårruller</td>
<td class="right">3.0</td>
<td class="center">ZZ  


     </td>
<td>86.08696 NOK</td>
<td>S,  15.0% </td>
<td>
</td>
<td class="right">258.26  NOK</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"> </td>
<td class="small">
<div><b>Orderline reference: </b>6</div>
</td>
<td colspan="6"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>15</td>
<td>K1</td>
<td>Kjøretillegg sone 1</td>
<td class="right">1.0</td>
<td class="center">ZZ  


     </td>
<td>86.08696 NOK</td>
<td>S,  15.0% </td>
<td>
</td>
<td class="right">86.09  NOK</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"> </td>
<td class="small">
<div><b>Orderline reference: </b>6</div>
</td>
<td colspan="6"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>16</td>
<td>4766</td>
<td>Kamskjell maki, 8 biter</td>
<td class="right">2.0</td>
<td class="center">ZZ  


     </td>
<td>82.6087 NOK</td>
<td>S,  15.0% </td>
<td>
</td>
<td class="right">165.22  NOK</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"> </td>
<td class="small">
<div><b>Additional information </b>- spicy</div>
<div><b>Orderline reference: </b>7</div>
</td>
<td colspan="6"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>17</td>
<td>4730</td>
<td>Sashimi liten, 10 biter</td>
<td class="right">2.0</td>
<td class="center">ZZ  


     </td>
<td>138.26087 NOK</td>
<td>S,  15.0% </td>
<td>
</td>
<td class="right">276.52  NOK</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"> </td>
<td class="small">
<div><b>Additional information </b>- spicy</div>
<div><b>Orderline reference: </b>7</div>
</td>
<td colspan="6"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>18</td>
<td>K1-K</td>
<td>Kjøretillegg kveld/helg sone 1</td>
<td class="right">1.0</td>
<td class="center">ZZ  


     </td>
<td>129.56522 NOK</td>
<td>S,  15.0% </td>
<td>
</td>
<td class="right">129.57  NOK</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"> </td>
<td class="small">
<div><b>Orderline reference: </b>7</div>
</td>
<td colspan="6"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>19</td>
<td>4740</td>
<td>Medium mix, 16 biter</td>
<td class="right">1.0</td>
<td class="center">ZZ  


     </td>
<td>225.21739 NOK</td>
<td>S,  15.0% </td>
<td>
</td>
<td class="right">225.22  NOK</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"> </td>
<td class="small">
<div><b>Additional information </b>- -smørfisk - +laks</div>
<div><b>Orderline reference: </b>8</div>
</td>
<td colspan="6"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>20</td>
<td>K1</td>
<td>Kjøretillegg sone 1</td>
<td class="right">1.0</td>
<td class="center">ZZ  


     </td>
<td>86.08696 NOK</td>
<td>S,  15.0% </td>
<td>
</td>
<td class="right">86.09  NOK</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"> </td>
<td class="small">
<div><b>Additional information </b>- -smørfisk - +laks</div>
<div><b>Orderline reference: </b>8</div>
</td>
<td colspan="6"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>21</td>
<td>5082</td>
<td>Meny 3, 16 biter</td>
<td class="right">1.0</td>
<td class="center">ZZ  


     </td>
<td>181.73913 NOK</td>
<td>S,  15.0% </td>
<td>
</td>
<td class="right">181.74  NOK</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"> </td>
<td class="small">
<div><b>Orderline reference: </b>9</div>
</td>
<td colspan="6"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>22</td>
<td>K1</td>
<td>Kjøretillegg sone 1</td>
<td class="right">1.0</td>
<td class="center">ZZ  


     </td>
<td>86.08696 NOK</td>
<td>S,  15.0% </td>
<td>
</td>
<td class="right">86.09  NOK</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"> </td>
<td class="small">
<div><b>Orderline reference: </b>9</div>
</td>
<td colspan="6"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>23</td>
<td>4740</td>
<td>Medium mix, 16 biter</td>
<td class="right">3.0</td>
<td class="center">ZZ  


     </td>
<td>225.21739 NOK</td>
<td>S,  15.0% </td>
<td>
</td>
<td class="right">675.65  NOK</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"> </td>
<td class="small">
<div><b>Additional information </b>- 1-smør+laks</div>
<div><b>Orderline reference: </b>10</div>
</td>
<td colspan="6"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>24</td>
<td>K1</td>
<td>Kjøretillegg sone 1</td>
<td class="right">1.0</td>
<td class="center">ZZ  


     </td>
<td>86.08696 NOK</td>
<td>S,  15.0% </td>
<td>
</td>
<td class="right">86.09  NOK</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"> </td>
<td class="small">
<div><b>Additional information </b>- 1-smør+laks</div>
<div><b>Orderline reference: </b>10</div>
</td>
<td colspan="6"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>25</td>
<td>5941</td>
<td>Stekte nudler m/ kylling</td>
<td class="right">3.0</td>
<td class="center">ZZ  


     </td>
<td>190.43478 NOK</td>
<td>S,  15.0% </td>
<td>
</td>
<td class="right">571.30  NOK</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"> </td>
<td class="small">
<div><b>Orderline reference: </b>11</div>
</td>
<td colspan="6"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>26</td>
<td>K1</td>
<td>Kjøretillegg sone 1</td>
<td class="right">1.0</td>
<td class="center">ZZ  


     </td>
<td>86.08696 NOK</td>
<td>S,  15.0% </td>
<td>
</td>
<td class="right">86.09  NOK</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"> </td>
<td class="small">
<div><b>Orderline reference: </b>11</div>
</td>
<td colspan="6"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>27</td>
<td>106</td>
<td>1 1/2 L. Pepsi Max</td>
<td class="right">1.0</td>
<td class="center">ZZ  


     </td>
<td>42.6087 NOK</td>
<td>S,  15.0% </td>
<td>
</td>
<td class="right">42.61  NOK</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"> </td>
<td class="small">
<div><b>Orderline reference: </b>11</div>
</td>
<td colspan="6"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>28</td>
<td>5051</td>
<td>Pad Thai</td>
<td class="right">3.0</td>
<td class="center">ZZ  


     </td>
<td>164.34783 NOK</td>
<td>S,  15.0% </td>
<td>
</td>
<td class="right">493.04  NOK</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"> </td>
<td class="small">
<div><b>Additional information </b>- m/kylling</div>
<div><b>Orderline reference: </b>12</div>
</td>
<td colspan="6"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>29</td>
<td>5015</td>
<td>Laksmaki, 8 biter</td>
<td class="right">1.0</td>
<td class="center">ZZ  


     </td>
<td>68.69565 NOK</td>
<td>S,  15.0% </td>
<td>
</td>
<td class="right">68.70  NOK</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"> </td>
<td class="small">
<div><b>Additional information </b>- m/kylling</div>
<div><b>Orderline reference: </b>12</div>
</td>
<td colspan="6"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>30</td>
<td>5081</td>
<td>Meny 2, 10 biter</td>
<td class="right">1.0</td>
<td class="center">ZZ  


     </td>
<td>126.08696 NOK</td>
<td>S,  15.0% </td>
<td>
</td>
<td class="right">126.09  NOK</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"> </td>
<td class="small">
<div><b>Orderline reference: </b>12</div>
</td>
<td colspan="6"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>31</td>
<td>5074</td>
<td>Bun Bo Xao</td>
<td class="right">1.0</td>
<td class="center">ZZ  


     </td>
<td>155.65217 NOK</td>
<td>S,  15.0% </td>
<td>
</td>
<td class="right">155.65  NOK</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"> </td>
<td class="small">
<div><b>Orderline reference: </b>12</div>
</td>
<td colspan="6"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>32</td>
<td>5003</td>
<td>Vårruller</td>
<td class="right">1.0</td>
<td class="center">ZZ  


     </td>
<td>68.69565 NOK</td>
<td>S,  15.0% </td>
<td>
</td>
<td class="right">68.70  NOK</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"> </td>
<td class="small">
<div><b>Orderline reference: </b>12</div>
</td>
<td colspan="6"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>33</td>
<td>K1</td>
<td>Kjøretillegg sone 1</td>
<td class="right">1.0</td>
<td class="center">ZZ  


     </td>
<td>86.08696 NOK</td>
<td>S,  15.0% </td>
<td>
</td>
<td class="right">86.09  NOK</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"> </td>
<td class="small">
<div><b>Orderline reference: </b>12</div>
</td>
<td colspan="6"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>34</td>
<td>5052</td>
<td>Biff Brokkoli</td>
<td class="right">1.0</td>
<td class="center">ZZ  


     </td>
<td>164.34783 NOK</td>
<td>S,  15.0% </td>
<td>
</td>
<td class="right">164.35  NOK</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"> </td>
<td class="small">
<div><b>Orderline reference: </b>13</div>
</td>
<td colspan="6"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>35</td>
<td>K1</td>
<td>Kjøretillegg sone 1</td>
<td class="right">1.0</td>
<td class="center">ZZ  


     </td>
<td>86.08696 NOK</td>
<td>S,  15.0% </td>
<td>
</td>
<td class="right">86.09  NOK</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"> </td>
<td class="small">
<div><b>Orderline reference: </b>13</div>
</td>
<td colspan="6"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>36</td>
<td>4740</td>
<td>Medium mix, 16 biter</td>
<td class="right">2.0</td>
<td class="center">ZZ  


     </td>
<td>225.21739 NOK</td>
<td>S,  15.0% </td>
<td>
</td>
<td class="right">450.43  NOK</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"> </td>
<td class="small">
<div><b>Orderline reference: </b>14</div>
</td>
<td colspan="6"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>37</td>
<td>K1</td>
<td>Kjøretillegg sone 1</td>
<td class="right">1.0</td>
<td class="center">ZZ  


     </td>
<td>86.08696 NOK</td>
<td>S,  15.0% </td>
<td>
</td>
<td class="right">86.09  NOK</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"> </td>
<td class="small">
<div><b>Orderline reference: </b>14</div>
</td>
<td colspan="6"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>38</td>
<td>4091</td>
<td>Nan</td>
<td class="right">1.0</td>
<td class="center">ZZ  


     </td>
<td>47.82609 NOK</td>
<td>S,  15.0% </td>
<td>
</td>
<td class="right">47.83  NOK</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"> </td>
<td class="small">
<div><b>Orderline reference: </b>15</div>
</td>
<td colspan="6"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>39</td>
<td>4033</td>
<td>Chicken Tikka</td>
<td class="right">1.0</td>
<td class="center">ZZ  


     </td>
<td>233.91304 NOK</td>
<td>S,  15.0% </td>
<td>
</td>
<td class="right">233.91  NOK</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"> </td>
<td class="small">
<div><b>Orderline reference: </b>15</div>
</td>
<td colspan="6"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>40</td>
<td>4042</td>
<td>Chicken Korma</td>
<td class="right">1.0</td>
<td class="center">ZZ  


     </td>
<td>225.21739 NOK</td>
<td>S,  15.0% </td>
<td>
</td>
<td class="right">225.22  NOK</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"> </td>
<td class="small">
<div><b>Orderline reference: </b>15</div>
</td>
<td colspan="6"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>41</td>
<td>4046</td>
<td>Chicken Kadahi</td>
<td class="right">1.0</td>
<td class="center">ZZ  


     </td>
<td>225.21739 NOK</td>
<td>S,  15.0% </td>
<td>
</td>
<td class="right">225.22  NOK</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"> </td>
<td class="small">
<div><b>Orderline reference: </b>15</div>
</td>
<td colspan="6"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>42</td>
<td>4034</td>
<td>Garlic Chicken</td>
<td class="right">1.0</td>
<td class="center">ZZ  


     </td>
<td>239.13043 NOK</td>
<td>S,  15.0% </td>
<td>
</td>
<td class="right">239.13  NOK</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"> </td>
<td class="small">
<div><b>Orderline reference: </b>15</div>
</td>
<td colspan="6"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>43</td>
<td>4052</td>
<td>Lamb Korma</td>
<td class="right">1.0</td>
<td class="center">ZZ  


     </td>
<td>233.04348 NOK</td>
<td>S,  15.0% </td>
<td>
</td>
<td class="right">233.04  NOK</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"> </td>
<td class="small">
<div><b>Orderline reference: </b>15</div>
</td>
<td colspan="6"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>44</td>
<td>K1</td>
<td>Kjøretillegg sone 1</td>
<td class="right">1.0</td>
<td class="center">ZZ  


     </td>
<td>86.08696 NOK</td>
<td>S,  15.0% </td>
<td>
</td>
<td class="right">86.09  NOK</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"> </td>
<td class="small">
<div><b>Orderline reference: </b>15</div>
</td>
<td colspan="6"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>45</td>
<td>4740</td>
<td>Medium mix, 16 biter</td>
<td class="right">1.0</td>
<td class="center">ZZ  


     </td>
<td>225.21739 NOK</td>
<td>S,  15.0% </td>
<td>
</td>
<td class="right">225.22  NOK</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"> </td>
<td class="small">
<div><b>Orderline reference: </b>16</div>
</td>
<td colspan="6"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>46</td>
<td>K1</td>
<td>Kjøretillegg sone 1</td>
<td class="right">1.0</td>
<td class="center">ZZ  


     </td>
<td>86.08696 NOK</td>
<td>S,  15.0% </td>
<td>
</td>
<td class="right">86.09  NOK</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"> </td>
<td class="small">
<div><b>Orderline reference: </b>16</div>
</td>
<td colspan="6"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>47</td>
<td>4740</td>
<td>Medium mix, 16 biter</td>
<td class="right">2.0</td>
<td class="center">ZZ  


     </td>
<td>225.21739 NOK</td>
<td>S,  15.0% </td>
<td>
</td>
<td class="right">450.43  NOK</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"> </td>
<td class="small">
<div><b>Additional information </b>- u/ smørfisk</div>
<div><b>Orderline reference: </b>17</div>
</td>
<td colspan="6"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>48</td>
<td>K1</td>
<td>Kjøretillegg sone 1</td>
<td class="right">1.0</td>
<td class="center">ZZ  


     </td>
<td>86.08696 NOK</td>
<td>S,  15.0% </td>
<td>
</td>
<td class="right">86.09  NOK</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"> </td>
<td class="small">
<div><b>Additional information </b>- u/ smørfisk</div>
<div><b>Orderline reference: </b>17</div>
</td>
<td colspan="6"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>49</td>
<td>
</td>
<td>Fakturgebyr</td>
<td class="right">1.0</td>
<td class="center">ZZ  


     </td>
<td>77.3913 NOK</td>
<td>S,  15.0% </td>
<td>
</td>
<td class="right">77.39  NOK</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"> </td>
<td class="small">
<div><b>Orderline reference: </b>17</div>
</td>
<td colspan="6"> </td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What libraries did you try already and where did you have trouble with them?

Comment: Are you looking to render the pdf client side or server side?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/564650/convert-html-to-pdf-in-net?rq=1 maybe you will find here an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564650/convert-html-to-pdf-in-net).

I will list down the basic steps:

1.) Download and install wkhtmtopdf from [here](http://wkhtmtopdf)
2.) Install Nuget package using below command:

```
Install-Package Codaxy.WkHtmlToPdf
```

3.) Use below wrapper class to convert html to pdf:

```
PdfConvert.ConvertHtmlToPdf(new PdfDocument 
{ 
    Url = "http://wkhtmltopdf.org/",
    HeaderLeft = "[title]",
    HeaderRight = "[date] [time]",
    FooterCenter = "Page [page] of [topage]"

}, new PdfOutput 
{
    OutputFilePath = "wkhtmltopdf-page.pdf"
});
```

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to do this is Rotativa with ActionAsPdf. If you need an example, let me know. This is a link which describes how to use it easily:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jXP3achaGbA

Answer (score -2):

Well Try for the HTML2Canvas libary it will provide you the Conversation from HTMl to PDF.
Or Jspdf it will work for you.

if more details are required let me know.