# How to download an MVC view as a PDF?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm currently coding in Visual Studio 2015. It's for a school project and I need to download a view as a PDF. I tried using a lot of methods posted here but can't seem to get it to work. It's a simple view with information displayed from tables in a view and I want to download the view as a PDF. Any easy suggestions.

Comment: First easy suggestion is to show some code you've tried so far, alongside with the errors you've got.

Answer (score 0):

if you mean convert html to pdf, you can refer to below post

[Convert HTML to PDF in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564650/convert-html-to-pdf-in-net)

Answer (score 0):

Actually your question is not clear. Anyways if you have that pdf file you may achieve that with FileResult method in Controller [Refer this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/create-a-pdf-file-and-download-using-Asp-Net-mvc/)

Or else if you want that particular view as it exactly as in pdf u may add a Save as PDF button in your page and make that button action same as Ctrl+P action as PDF.

Or else if you want another way please review your question and provide correct requirements.

Answer (score 0):

> How to download an MVC view as a PDF? using Rotativa

1. **Install NuGet Package**

```
Install-Package Rotativa -Version 1.7.4-rc
```

2. **C# MVC**

```
//UserController
public ActionResult Download(string encryptReportId)
{
    //business login to bind this view
    //bind view using this encryptReportId
    return View();
}

public ActionResult DownloadViewAsPDF(string encryptId)
{
    return new Rotativa.ActionAsPdf("Download", new { encryptReportId = encryptReportId }) { FileName = "TestingPdf.pdf" };
}
```

3. **Html**

```
//use ajax call for this DownloadViewAsPDF of User Controller
$.ajax({
    url: "/User/DownloadViewAsPDF",
    data: {
        encryptId ': id,//id can be get on download button click event as a parameter
    },
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(result) {
        alert("Report Downloaded as PDF!!");
    },
    error: function(errormessage) {
        alert(errormessage.responseText);
    }
});
```

I hope this will help.