# Fax Current WebPage using RightFax OpenText WebService

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-services, opentext, rightfax

I have a page with a fax button on it... when clicked it uses a dialog to capture the destination of the fax from a drop down list.

What I need to do is apply the print stylesheet and capture the webpage.

I am using RightFax webservice "OpenText" to send the fax.

How do I:

1: capture the HTML and style for the webpage
  2: serialize the HTML into a byte array so I can add it as an attachment

using MVC 5 and c#

Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: Fax a webpage <<shudder>> :).  Does OpenText expect HTML?  If so, I don't see how you can apply the print style sheet, do you mean you want to link to a print style sheet in the HTML?  Or is OpenText expecting a BMP?  You know you can access the HTML with `document.documentElement.innerHTML`

Comment: Shudder indeed...  OpenText takes a byte array into a property called "Attachment" ... I have a serialization method that takes an object and returns byte[]. It does not like string or htmlstring but it does like PDF. I don't want to save to disk, as I want this to be a seemless experience.

I am thinking xml ... but I am at a loss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to base your solution server side.  You'll need a page or service that takes a URL as a parameter, it will then need to

1. Use WebClient to load the website HTML from the URL

--If you can send a BMP byte[] to OpenText--

2. Use a toolkit like WebKit https://github.com/webkitdotnet/webkitdotnet to render the HTML to an image.
3. Send the BMP byte[] to OpenText

--If you can't send a BMP byte[] to OpenText--

2. Use a HTML to PDF converter [Convert HTML to PDF in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564650/convert-html-to-pdf-in-net)
3. Send the PDF to OpenText

The main point is that you'll be converting HTML to a binary object server side, and making the call to OpenText from the server too.