# How to convert HTML file to PDF

Tags: c#, html, pdf

I need to convert html file(report.html) that I create to PDF,

I tried:

```
PdfDocument pdf = PdfGenerator.GeneratePdf(htmlFilePath, PageSize.A4);
pdf.Save(pdfFileName);
```

But without success. Should I close chrome driver before I start creating PDF or is my code wrong?

Error message:
Could not load file or assembly 'HtmlRenderer, Version=1.5.0.5, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I send same htmlFilePath as for creating HTML.

Comment: What went wrong?  What was the error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert HTML to PDF in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564650/convert-html-to-pdf-in-net)

Answer (score 0):

You must see warning list(not error list). In my case I can not use .net framework dll in .netcore project.

my warning list has one warning about that:

Warning NU1701  Package 'HtmlRenderer.Core 1.5.0.5' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.

Answer (score -1):

Problem was with nuget, when i reference one project that have HtmlRenderer to another HtmlRenderer.dll was not copied.

Now i have other problem PDF generate only path of html file.
[image]