# Display string as HTML view on printer, PDF, OneNote, Fax, XPS, etc

Tags: c#, html, .net, vb.net

I would like to print `HTML` view from `string` no matter what kind of printer user choose. I'm trying to use `System.Drawing` library and method `DrawString()` but it is not what I'm expecting. I have to pass raw `HTML` tags from `string` and display view. How can I do that?

Comment: By "HTML view" do you mean the raw HTML with tags or do you mean the rendered HTML?

Comment: @AndrewMorton I'm expecting rendered HTML view, on PDF, printer, fax, etc.

Comment: If you [Convert HTML to PDF in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/q/564650/1115360) (I recommend looking at all the answers) then you only have the problem of printing a PDF to the remaining formats.