# Is there a way to save outlook item to pdf in visual studio?

Tags: c#, pdf, outlook, save, outlook-addin

I need to deploy an add-in to Outlook. I have a old VBA macro that works, (save an Outlook  item do pdf). But I need a modern way to deploy it to all users. Is it possible in Visual Studio Windows Form? There is a template?

Answer (score 0):

You can use any .net components for getting the job done if you develop a COM add-in (for example, a VSTO based one). Basically, you may get the `HTMLBody` property value and save it using the .pdf file format. See [Convert HTML to PDF in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564650/convert-html-to-pdf-in-net) for more information.

Take a look at the [Walkthrough: Create your first VSTO Add-in for Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-creating-your-first-vsto-add-in-for-outlook?view=vs-2019) article to get started quickly.