# I need to create PDF from user control HTML in ASP.NET webforms ? How do i get html from user control and then convert that HTML to PDF?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

The purpose of this is working on ASP.NET webform application. My requirement is to get user control rendered html and then convert that html to pdf and attach as a document in database.
I have used multiple techniques like getting html from http web request but could not found my desired solution. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Seems like a duplicate ofL https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564650/convert-html-to-pdf-in-net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could look at the OpenHtmlToPdf

https://github.com/vilppu/OpenHtmlToPdf

I think it will do what you need.

You will create the PDF and save it as a blob within your database is my understanding of your requirement.