# Export ms-office file with markups to pdf via pdftron

Tags: c#, pdf, ms-office, pdftron

MS Office has functionality to add markups and comments into document. This functionality is shown on the following picture
[image: example of document with markups]

The MS Office has option to generate PDF file from office file with markup, as a result pdf file will contain markups, comments etc.
[image: save as PDF]

I need to generate PDF file from office file on server machine but in my case I can not install MS Office on server machine to use Office API. I tried to use PDFTron to generate PDF file from office file but PDFTron does not export markups from office file to PDF file. How can I solve it?
What can I use to generated PDF file with markups if PDFTron does not support exporting markups in PDF file?

Comment: you could go the html to pdf route. There are many more libraries available for that and you don't need Word installed that way. Check out the available libraries in this amazing answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57810379/1623971

Comment: @Democrats, thank you for comment! The html to pdf route can applied only to file  with Open xml format like .docx, .pptx, .xlsx. But it case with binary file format (doc, xls, ppt) it won't work.

Comment: Is it possible to get an example Word file that has the markup you want to convert?