# Printing An HTML String Without Creating An HTML File?

Tags: c#, html, printing

How can I print an HTML string so all of the HTML tags are recognized and rendered correctly?  I imagine it's possible to create a .HTML file and print it, but if there is a way to do this without creating extra files I'd be interested in learning how.  Thanks!

Addendum:

```
pd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(PrintDocument_PrintPage);
pd.Print();
```

More code:

```
static private void PrintDocument_PrintPage(Object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e) {
    Font printFont = new Font("Courier New", 12);
    e.Graphics.DrawString("<b>Hello</b> world", printFont, Brushes.Black, 0, 0);
}
```

Printed result:

```
<b>Hello</b> world
```

Comment: What problem are you running into?  I'd think that sticking all of the appropriate characters into a `string` would work, but maybe not?

Comment: If you output correct HTML, it will be "recognized and rendered correctly". Where are you "printing" to? What are you using to view the HTML?

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work like that.  I really don't know what direction to go from here...

Comment: In what context? Are you saying you want to fetch and/or display dynamically generated HTML content?

Comment: I simply want to go from a C# string to a properly rendered HTML printout

Comment: see this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/174/how-do-i-print-an-html-document-from-a-web-service/768#768),
you can also see this [code project article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/printing/printhml.aspx), in which you can disable print dialog too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Graphics` object does not understand HTML, and `DrawString` will do exactly as requested, as you have found out.

You will need to use the Graphics object with a bold font for `Hello` and a non bold font for `world` and remove the HTML markup.

So, for a more general approach, you would need an HTML parser (such as the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)) and a way to translate the HTML to different fonts.

You may find it easier to use a [`WebBrowser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w290k23d.aspx) control and use it to print.

Comment: Can I go from a C# string directly to WebBrowserControl print without writing a separate file?

Comment: @sooprise - I didn't try this myself, but you should be able to use the [`DocumentStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentstream.aspx) directly.