# Print txt file using javascript

Tags: javascript, file, printing

I would like to know if it is possible to print a txt file located in the server using javascript. I have noticed that window.print() just opens the print dialog for the current web page

Comment: It is not possible with only javascript. You should use also ajax with or without some server scripting language.

Comment: You can't force someone to print a page if they don't want to. The print dialog is how users decide *how* to print something, or decide if they don't actually want to print anything.

Answer (score 15):

You can only open the print dialog for the user, and that is as it should be. If you only want to print the text document, there are a couple ways you can trigger the print dialog for it. They require following the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) (your HTML and TXT files need to be in the same domain).

The simplest way is to open a popup window with the text file, and call print on the window handle returned:

```
w = window.open('text.txt');
w.print();
```

If you want the user to preview the text file, you could use an iframe instead:
<sub>I recommend keeping JS out of HTML, this is just for example</sub>

```
<iframe id="textfile" src="text.txt"></iframe>
<button onclick="print()">Print</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
function print() {
    var iframe = document.getElementById('textfile');
    iframe.contentWindow.print();
}
</script>
```

Comment: In his question, he is saying that he wants the file to be printed not just show the print dialog.

Comment: @sv_in, you're right, i forgot to add the disclaimer that you can't force a user to print something they don't want to.

Answer (score 3):

The JQuery option

```
<body>

    <div id="txtdiv"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      $('#txtdiv').load('trial.txt', function()
      {
        window.print(); //prints when text is loaded
      });

    </script>
 </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that `window.print()` just opens the print dialog for the current web page.

I would suggest that you write JavaScript code to open a new window, load the text into that window, and then call the `print()` function on that window.

Answer (score 1):

If you just do not want to delete the contents of the page and print some text from a file, you can do so here:

```
<body>

....some tags....

<script type="text/javascript">
// or onclick function
$.load('test.txt', function( printContent ){
    history.pushState( printContent, 'Print title', '/print_page' );
    document.write( printContent );
    if( window.print() ){
         document.location = '/back_page/';
         // or history.go(-1);
    } else {
         document.location = '/history/';
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score -3):

You can do this by creating a web service.

1. Create a web service, and do printing stuff in the webservice.
2. Call the web service from JavaScript.

If you are wondering how to do printing using webservice [there is a thread in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/174/how-do-i-print-an-html-document-from-a-web-service) which might help. Dont just look the question, browse the answer as well.