# Print file on a local printer using PHP with pop up printer window?

Tags: javascript, php, printing

i want to print file which contain in $file variable on a local printer. I want a pop up window just like Java Script window.print(). My question is that how i can do the same job using PHP only? [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37413742/11237192) is a solution but it does not show pop up window.

Answer (score 0):

As PHP runs on the host server only, there is no way to interact with the user using a popup window after the page loads as Javascript can. The easiest way would be to have PHP echo the Javascript commands.

Comment: can you explain it ?

Comment: This may be helpful - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11228280/print-txt-file-using-javascript